# Ruby : String not appended as desired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written the following class to obtain results from solr corresponding to a given query

```
class Recommendation
    class GetResults
            attr_accessor :query, :filter, :sort, :facet, :highlight, :filter_fields, :sort_order, :highlight_fields, :facet_query, :facet_fields, :sort_field
            def initialize(query, filter=false, sort=false, facet=false, highlight=false, filter_fields=nil, sort_order=nil, sort_field=nil, highlight_fields=nil, facet_query=nil, facet_fields=nil)
                    @query = query
                    @filter = filter||false
                    @sort = sort||false
                    @facet = facet||false
                    @highlight = highlight||false
                    @filter_fields = filter_fields||nil
                    @sort_order = sort_order||nil
                    @sort_field = sort_field||nil
                    @highlight_fields = highlight_fields||nil
                    @facet_query = facet_query||nil
                    @facet_fields = facet_fields||nil
            end

            def obtain_results
                    h=Net::HTTP.new('localhost',8983)
                    @query_path = '/solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=%s&wt=ruby' % query
                    if @filter==true
                            #puts "hello filter"
                            @query_path = @query_path.to_s + "&fl=%s" % @filter_fields
                            puts @query_path
                    end
                    if @sort==true
                            #puts "hello sort"
                            @query_path = @query_path.to_s + "&sort=%s "+"%s" % @sort_field,@sort_order
                            puts @query_path
                    end

                    #hsrep, data = h.get(@query_path)
                    #rsp = eval(data)
                    #puts rsp
            end
    end
end

results=Recommendation::GetResults.new(query='ring', filter=true, sort=true, filter_fields='allText,Price', sort_order='asc', sort_field='Price')
results.obtain_results
```

The problem with this is `@query_path` is not updated as desired.
The output is:

```
hello filter
/solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=ring&wt=ruby&fl=Price
hello sort
/solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=ring&wt=ruby&fl=Price&sort=%s
```

The desired output is:

```
hello filter
/solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=ring&wt=ruby&fl=allText,Price
hello sort
/solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=ring&wt=ruby&fl=allText,Price&sort=Price asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [positional arguments](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Arguments) in your method definition, i.e. you have to pass the arguments in the order you define them:

> When called, the arguments must be provided in the exact order. In other words, the arguments are positional.

```
# def initialize(query, filter=false, sort=false, facet=false, highlight=false, filter_fields=nil, sort_order=nil, sort_field=nil, highlight_fields=nil, facet_query=nil, facet_fields=nil)
#                  ^      ^             ^           ^              ^                 ^
#                  |      |             |           |              |                 |
GetResults.new( 'ring', true,         true,   'allText,Price',   'asc',           'Price')
```

The variable assignments in your method call (e.g. `filter=true`) do not refer to the arguments. They just set some local variables:

```
def test(foo=1, bar=2)
  [foo, bar]
end

bar = 3

test(bar=4, baz=5)  # this overwrites "bar" and defines a new variable "baz"
#=> [4, 5]          # note the order, "bar" doesn't refer to the method's "bar" argument 
bar
#=> 4
baz
#=> 5
```

You could use [keyword arguments](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) (Ruby 2.0):

> When calling a method with keyword arguments the arguments may appear in any order.

```
def initialize(query, filter: false, sort: false, facet: false, highlight: false, filter_fields: nil, sort_order: nil, sort_field: nil, highlight_fields: nil, facet_query: nil, facet_fields: nil)
  # ...
end
```

Or an options hash:

```
def initialize(query, options={})
  @query = query
  @filter = options.fetch(:filter, false)
  @sort = options.fetch(:sort, false)
  @facet = options.fetch(:facet, false)
  @highlight = options.fetch(:highlight, false)
  @filter_fields = options.fetch(:filter_fields, nil)
  @sort_order = options.fetch(:sort_order, nil)
  @sort_field = options.fetch(:sort_field, nil)
  @highlight_fields = options.fetch(:highlight_fields, nil)
  @facet_query = options.fetch(:facet_query, nil)
  @facet_fields = options.fetch(:facet_fields, nil)
end
```

Comment: Interesting way of doing it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer, but why dou you build this string in a such tedious way, when you can do :

```
# build a hash with your query params
query_params = { 
  foo:  'bar', 
  baz:  'baz',
  buzz: nil
}

query = query_params
          .reject{|k,v| v.nil? }        # reject params with no value
          .map{|(k,v)| "#{k}=#{v}" }    # interpolate to "key=value"
          .join('&')                    # => "foo=bar&baz=baz"

@query_path = "#{@query_path}?#{query}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Better than an answer!! Really apprecate the tip

Comment: you're welcome. I tend to think that each and every Ruby dev should try and learn all of [Enumerable's methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) by heart !

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way you are initializing your GetResults object.

This code (note `facet=false, highlight=false`):

```
results=Recommendation::GetResults.new(query='ring', filter=true, sort=true,
    facet=false, highlight=false, filter_fields='allText,Price', 
    sort_order='asc', sort_field='Price')

results.obtain_results
```

will give you the desired output:

```
hello filter
#=> /solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=ring&wt=ruby&fl=allText,Price

hello sort
#=> /solr/voylla/select/?indent=on&q=ring&wt=ruby&fl=allText,Price&sort=Price asc
```

Comment: @MademoiselleGeek why are you repeating the variable assignment inside the method call (`query=`, `filter=`, `sort=`, ...)? It's superfluous, misleading and the source of the OP's problem.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that the error lied in the initalizer, and simply copied the style used in the question without further refactoring. The proper way to rewrite this initialiser in Ruby 1.9 is to use an options hash, as detailed in your answer below (which I've already upvoted :-) )

Comment: You can of course use positional arguments, but you should call the initializer like `GetResults.new('ring', true, true, false, false, 'allText,Price', 'asc', 'Price')`

Comment: @Stefan : this is an option but to be clear what is what, i guess i'm ok with typing a few extra words.

Comment: @naka but that was the cause of your problem. You thought it was clear, it *looked* right, but it wasn't. You could as well type: `GetResults.new(shape='ring', delete_all=true, call_bob=true, makes_sense=false, ...)`. These variables are pointless and they can cause other problems: if any of these variables exists in the current scope, it's overwritten.